# Cannot find the knife tool (already in editing/ modeling mode)

Tags: osx

I apologize for the rather silly question; I've been looking around to see why the knife tool (or the rest of the extended tool box) does not show, but I could not find any solutions online.

I've attached a picture that should help clarify the issue. [image: knife tool not showing]

Please let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Comment: Don't think the knife tool is available for metaballs. Should convert it to a mesh before.

Comment: Hi. If you have an answer please add it using the answer box below instead of adding "(Answered)" to the title.

Comment: @RayMairlot
I apologize for the unrelated question, but how do you select an answer, I followed this [link] [1], but can't apply it here.

[1]: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: That link's advice won't work because you don't yet have an answer. I'm suggesting *you* write an answer. I presumed (perhaps incorrectly) that you had an answer because you put "Answered" in the title. If you don't have an answer, remove "Answered" from the title. If you do, write it below in the answer box.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think the knife tool is available for metaballs. Should convert it to a mesh before.